# OAuth 2.0 Flow how it works node-oauth2-server

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

While implementing OAuth Server in NodeJS with https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server

I'm trying to understand flow of OAuth 2.0

Somehow i'm successful with this npm package implementation, But I doubt, Something is going wrong.

I'll explain how i'm successful.

**1st REQUEST:**

```
POST: http://localhost:3000/oauth/token
grant_type=password
client_id=1011
client_secret=somesecret
username=admin
password=admin
```

**1st RESPONSE:**

```
{
token_type: "bearer"
access_token: "7f5261011fb0f84a4e193889fff4b7478f2a4cb2"
expires_in: 3600
refresh_token: "da83de41966979ced65b3841e1758335a811c0c2"
}
```

after getting access token, I'm sending another http call

**2nd REQUEST:**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/secret
Authorization: Bearer 7f5261011fb0f84a4e193889fff4b7478f2a4cb2
```

**2nd RESPONSE:**

```
{"data":"Secret area accessible"}
```

But here i'm fully confused about

**Question 1. Authorization_code part is missing**

**Question 2. In first call I need to send client_secret and user_password - If I sending both means oauth client is exposing secret to user(Browser) or User is providing password to OAuth Client.**

Please share me if any request/response pattern of whole OAuth 2.0 like below

```
a. browser -> oauth server POST /oauth/authorize?client_id,username,password
b. USER GRANTS PERMISSION
c. browser -> oauth server RESPONSE auth_code
d. browser -> oauth client POST auth_code
e. oauth_client -> oauth server POST auth_code
e. oauth server -> oauth_client  RESPONSE access_token
f. oauth_client  -> resource_server POST /resource?access_token (Question 3. But here how resource server validates access token is valid or not )
```

Answer (score 6):

OAuth 2.0 defines several ways of obtaining an access token through so-called "grants". Your requests show that you're currently using the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3. That grant is indeed exposing the username/password to the Client which is why it defeats most of the purpose of OAuth 2.0 and is for migration purposes only, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.7

The Authorization Code grant is a separate grant type by which a user is redirected with a browser to an authorization endpoint so that the Client stays out of the user authentication process. You seem to refer to that in the flow described in a.-f. Since that is a different grant type, you won't see the "authorization code" as part of the resource owner password credentials grant.

In a correct Authorization Code grant flow, a. would be a redirect instead of a POST as in: `a. browser -> oauth server Redirect /oauth/authorize?client_id,response_type=code`